# Loop Excel code for each line until blank cell is found

Tags: excel, vba, loops, excel-indirect

I have the following code That I need to loop for ~100 rows. Instead of writing out for each row, is there a way to add a loop feature in here to repeat until a row is blank? I am having trouble figuring out the Do While Loop feature and incorporating it within the code below. Thanks!

```
 Sub Excel_INDIRECT_Function()

 'declare a variable
    Dim ws As Worksheet

 Set ws = Worksheets("TOC")

    'apply the Excel INDIRECT function

ws.Range("$F8").Formula = "=INDIRECT($W8&""Q24"")"
ws.Range("$G8").Formula = "=INDIRECT($W8&""Q30"")"
ws.Range("$I8").Formula = "=INDIRECT($W8&""I56"")"
ws.Range("$J8").Formula = "=INDIRECT($W8&""Q34"")"
ws.Range("$K8").Formula = "=INDIRECT($W8&""D7"")"
ws.Range("$L8").Formula = "=INDIRECT($W8&""L56"")"
ws.Range("$M8").Formula = "=INDIRECT($W8&""M56"")"
ws.Range("$N8").Formula = "=INDIRECT($W8&""N56"")"
ws.Range("$O8").Formula = "=INDIRECT($W8&""O56"")"
ws.Range("$R8").Formula = "=INDIRECT($W8&""D6"")"

End Sub
```

I am looking to get this accomplished for multiple rows without writing this code ~100 times. Thanks so much.

Comment: Is column `H` and `P` missing by accident or in purpose? And how do you expect this to be loopable if this part `""Q24""` in the `Indirect` formula doesn't show any pattern? I recommend to separate data from code. Make a hidden sheet with a list with 2 columns the first takes the address of the range `"$F8"` and the second takes the address of the indirect `$W8&""Q24""` then loop over that hidden sheet range.

Comment: Otherwise looping would olny be possible if there is a pattern to find out how the range part `"$F8"` and indirect `$W8&""Q24""` part are determined. Can you tell us this pattern? • Note that an extensive use of `Indirect` can make calculation of your sheet extremely slow as it is a volatile function.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. H, P and Q will be deleted so those will shift but trying to loop these. The problem is we have a prepopulated table of contents that just has a list of names. From there we create tabs for each name and have analysts complete the required info on each tab. At the end, I want to hit a macro that pulls pertinent data up to the table of contents as this info changes each quarter and a new TOC is sent out. So we could have up to 100 tabs in any quarter.

Comment: the person below got it working for me. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you need a loop.

This code will put the formulas in columns F, G etc. from row 8 down to the last row of data in column W.

```
Sub Excel_INDIRECT_Function()
'declare a variable
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lngLastRow As Long

    Set ws = Worksheets("TOC")
    
    lngLastRow = ws.Range("W" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'apply the Excel INDIRECT function

    ws.Range("F8:F" & lngLastRow).Formula = "=INDIRECT($W8&""Q24"")"
    ws.Range("G8:G" & lngLastRow).Formula = "=INDIRECT($W8&""Q30"")"
    ws.Range("I8:I" & lngLastRow).Formula = "=INDIRECT($W8&""I56"")"
    ws.Range("J8:J" & lngLastRow).Formula = "=INDIRECT($W8&""Q34"")"
    ws.Range("K8:K" & lngLastRow).Formula = "=INDIRECT($W8&""D7"")"
    ws.Range("L8:L" & lngLastRow).Formula = "=INDIRECT($W8&""L56"")"
    ws.Range("M8:M" & lngLastRow).Formula = "=INDIRECT($W8&""M56"")"
    ws.Range("N8:N" & lngLastRow).Formula = "=INDIRECT($W8&""N56"")"
    ws.Range("O8:O" & lngLastRow).Formula = "=INDIRECT($W8&""O56"")"
    ws.Range("R8:R" & lngLastRow).Formula = "=INDIRECT($W8&""D6"")"

End Sub
```